# Perform calculations between rows in a data frame and compare the result value to a row value in the previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with the folowing format:

```
ID     Y    M  ...  distanceWindow  timeWindow                dateTime
0       30218  2010  1.0  ...        5.504462   11.266509 2010-01-01 04:05:12.000
1       30219  2010  1.0  ...        6.302367   13.351246 2010-01-01 13:24:11.000
2       30220  2010  1.0  ...        5.371478   10.919053 2010-01-01 15:11:29.000
3       30221  2010  1.0  ...        6.860901   14.810562 2010-01-01 22:18:54.000
4       30223  2010  1.0  ...        6.767812   14.567342 2010-01-02 17:29:43.000
...       ...   ...  ...  ...             ...         ...                     ...
```

I want to find the absolute value of the difference between the dateTime of 0 and dateTime 1, then see if the value is less than the timeWindow value 0. If it is less, then I will create a new column ['main'] and set its value to true, other wise set it to false.

I want to do this with all rows against all subsequent rows. 0 against 1, 0 against 2, 0 against 3.....
Then 1 against 2, 1 against 3, and so on.

So far I was trying to use apply with a lambda and shift, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to go.

```
 df['main'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: True if (
           abs(df['dateTime'] - df['dateTime'].shift(periods=1))) < df["timeWindow"]
                else False)
```

Comment: The number of comparison results will be much greater than the number of rows in your dataframe.

Comment: From my description, do you see a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: I was thinking of making a copy of the dataset to compare to itself. Like a for in for loop. Would something like that be recommended?